# Expo React project with webpack: Unable to run on port 3000 using npx expo start --web -p 3000

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, port

I am working on an Expo React project that utilizes webpack, and I am encountering an issue when trying to run my app on port 3000 using the command npx expo start --web -p 3000. Instead of my app, Metro is running on port 3000, and my app runs in port 19006.

How can I make sure my Expo React app runs on port 3000?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.